# How to solve this error `Path does not exist /home/runner/work/cypress-tests/cypress-tests/cypress/screenshots`?

Tags: yaml, cypress, github-actions

I have a Github workflow and below is the file:

```
workflow_dispatch:  

jobs:
  cypress-run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 15
    steps:
      - run: echo "TEMP PIPELINE FOR Fix-GithubSecrets"
      - run: echo "The job was automatically triggered by a ${{ github.event_name }} event."
      - run: echo "This job is now running on a ${{ runner.os }} server hosted by GitHub!"
      - run: echo "The name of your branch is ${{ github.ref }} and your repository is ${{ github.repository }}."
      
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: Run npm ci
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      - run: npm ci

      - name: Run Cypress Tests
        env:
          CYPRESS_QA_AUTH_TOKEN_BUYER: ${{ secrets.QA_AUTH_TOKEN_BUYER }}
          CYPRESS_QA_AUTH_TOKEN_INTERNAL: ${{ secrets.QA_AUTH_TOKEN_INTERNAL }}
          CYPRESS_QA_AUTH_TOKEN_SELLER: ${{ secrets.QA_AUTH_TOKEN_SELLER }}
          CYPRESS_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_PROJECT_ID }}
          CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          CYPRESS_APIPASSWORD: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_APIPASSWORD }}
          CYPRESS_APIUSERNAME: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_APIUSERNAME }}
          CYPRESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CYPRESS_TOKEN }}
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v2
        with:
          record: true

      - name: Upload Screenshot Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        if: failure()
        with:
          name: cypress-screenshots
          path: cypress/screenshots
```

And when I run this I am getting error:  `Path does not exist /home/runner/work/cypress-tests/cypress-tests/cypress/screenshots`

How do I create the screenshot folder with the above workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Add a step creating the folder first:

```yaml
      - name: Run Cypress Tests
        ...
      - name: Create folder
        run: |
          mkdir -p cypress/screenshots
      - name: Upload Screenshot Artifacts
        ...
```

You can seen other examples in "[How to create a folder in github workflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67998421/6309)".

Comment: did not work @vonC Still seeing the same error. This is my yml file now `- name: Create folder
        run: mkdir -p cypress/screenshots

      - name: Upload Screenshot Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        if: failure()
        with:
          name: cypress-screenshots
          path: cypress/screenshots `

Comment: @anyuzer Can you try without the last `Upload Screenshot Artifacts`? Just to check if the folder is created.